# C#: Inheritance and IDisposable - strange issue

Tags: c#, inheritance, idisposable

can anyone help, i have a small issue, i have an interface and also a base interface, when i try to do

```
  .Dispose()
```

It doesn't find the method as its implemented on my sub class NOT base.. and it always seems to want to call the base - even though i specifically put the namespace in front of the parameter on the constructor.

Here is some code to explain it better, basically there are 2 IhouseRepository (interfaces), 1 is the base interface and one is the subclass interface.

In the constructor i have specifically said its MarkSmith.Data (and not MarkSmith.DataBase) but it keeps pickup up the DataBase version where Dispose is not implemented.

My idea was to implement IDisposable in all subclasses and should be there responsibility to dispose.

In the constructor i have a put a single line that calls the IhouseRepository and i "CAN" access Dispose - so it does work - Why it works here on not on the param passed to the constructor is a mystery :-)

But the param on the constructor seems to be forcing the namespace DataBase and not Data

I suppose i could rename all my Interfaces on the base project to IHouseRepositoryBase but i don't understand why this is happening.

Any help really appreciated

```
public class HouseService : ServiceBase.HouseService, IHouseService
{
    public HouseService(MarkSmith.Data.IHouseRepository repository)
        : base(repository) 
    {

        MarkSmith.Data.IHouseRepository test =
            new MarkSmith.Data.HouseRepository(new MyDataContext);
        test.Dispose(); // THIS WORKS! NO PROBLEMS
    }

    // Dispose() calls Dispose(true)
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }


    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            // free managed resources
            if (repository != null)
            {
                repository.Dispose(); // THIS FAILS .. IT IS CALLING NS DATABASE
            }
        }
```

Comment: I must admit that I did not fully understand your question. Does IHouseRepository derive from IDisposable? If no, why not?

Comment: Your code also needs to general cleaning, in my opinnion (best practices generally recommend against sub-classes). I'm having a hard time following what you've done. Where did you implement IDisposable?

Comment: What does "IT IS CALLING NS DATABASE" mean?

Comment: What is the type of "repository" in the Dispose? Is it really a "MarkSmith.Data.IHouseRepository"? Can I see more of the code? E.g. base class implementation?

Comment: "In the constructor i have specifically said its MarkSmith.Data (and not MarkSmith.DataBase) but it keeps pickup up the DataBase version where Dispose is not implemented.". None of this makes any sense. I need to see the code to help you.

Comment: IT IS CALLING NS DATABASE means its calling Dispose on the namespace DATABASE rather than DATA

Comment: Heinzi - yes originally i was open implementing my IDisposable in my subclasses - my base classes contain code but ARE abstract.

Comment: Well it sounds like the member variable "repository" in your base class is defined as a "MarkSmith.Data.IHouseRepository", but I can't tell without seeing the code.

Comment: Its now working, sorry if my explanation was not spot on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't your overloaded `Dispose()` method need to be `virtual` so that subclasses can override its implementation?  Otherwise, the method that ends up getting called will depend on what interface you're calling it through.

Also, if all subclasses should be required to implement `IDisposable`, then the base class should implement `IDisposable` as well -- this causes the compiler to enforce it.

Comment: Thnaks daniel, i got a bit confused .. anyway with your suggestion its working.. Basically i my base class inherit from IDisposable but are implemented as abstract .. and then in the subclass these are overriden .. Now all works!

Answer (score 1):

If you followed the recommended pattern then your Dispose method in the HouseRepository is not virtual. It means that which one will be called is statically determined compile time based on the type of the variable you use to access it - not on the type of the instance in the variable.

This is just general considerations, but this is as far as I can go because in your code sample the member definition for the repository is not present.